# Trying to set interests on campaign details to boost a post on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I just started boosting posts on my Facebook page. When I created the boost I set several interests to target efficiently my prospects. Nevertheless I think a bug happened and the interests were not taken into account when I published my boost. 
When I click on the amount of money left I have here :
[image: Clicking on "Money Left" on boosted post]

I then end up on a modal like this :

[image: Audience Details]

This modal specifies the audience details on the right down side corner and I see that no interests is specified here, so I am pretty sure a bug happened here!

How can I fix that and specify interest for my targeted audience even if the boost was already created?